# Getting the visible number of rows (or height) of the terminal in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, tty

Looking at the [TTY node module](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html), I can access process.stdout.rows which returns "*A number specifying the number of rows the TTY currently has*." But obviously the **available** ones and **not** the **visible** ones as the following code:

```
let lines = process.stdout.rows

// Clear console
process.stdout.write('\x1Bc')

for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    console.log(1)
  } else if (i === Math.round(lines / 2)) {
    console.log('halfwayish')
  } else if (i === lines - 1) {
    console.log('end')
  } else {
    console.log('\r\n')
  }
}
```

outputs:

[image]

How can I make it so that `end` is at the end, `halfwayish` is halfwayish and `1` is at the first line without having to scroll in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this works for You.
final solutions after edit:

```
let lines = process.stdout.rows

// Clear console
process.stdout.write('\x1Bc');
var stop = false;
for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    console.log(1);
  } else if (i === Math.round(lines / 4)) {
    console.log('halfwayish');
  } else if (i === lines/2) {
    stop = true;
    console.log('end');
  } else if(stop === false){
    console.log('\r\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It will output the lines with no spaces between them.

Comment: Please check code after my edit with console.log('\r\n') after each if statement, and commented out else console.log('\r\n')

Comment: I want `end` to be at the end, `halfwayish` to be halfwayish and `1` to be at the first line.  I have updated my question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

for me this worked.
Basically take out the newlines

```
process.stdout.on('resize', () => {
 process.stdout.write('\x1Bc')
 var lines = process.stdout.rows
 for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
        console.log(1)
    } else if (i === Math.round(lines / 2)) {
        console.log('halfwayish')
    } else if (i === lines - 1) {
        console.log('end')
    } else {
        console.log("")
    }
 }
});
```

I think the console.log itself adds a new line, and you adding another new line is making it go beyond what the lines variable has.